# Twitter Feed not showing up on my website

Tags: html, twitter, web, widget

So I'm still fairly new to web page design and I've been messing around with dreamweaver some lately. When trying to add a twitter feed to my website, I stumbled upon twitter's resources where you are basically supposed to copy [the code they give you here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) and paste it where you want it on your website. I did that and nothing happened at all. I've tried messing with it some and nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing? Are you supposed to add anything to it? I'm just pasting the code it generates into a div container that I have placed on my website.

Even when pasting only the code to a document in notepad and opening that, the feed doesn't show.

```
<div id="extracontent">
    <center>twitter feed</center>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>;
    <script>
        new TWTR.Widget({
            version: 2,
            type: 'profile',
            rpp: 4,
            interval: 30000,
            width: 250,
            height: 300,
            theme: {
                shell: {
                    background: '#333333',
                    color: '#ffffff'
                },
                tweets: {
                    background: '#000000',
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    links: '#4aed05'
                }
            },
            features: {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: false,
                live: false,
                behavior: 'all'
            }
        }).render().setUser('Jagdevelopment').start();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing your exact code - please post the relevant parts.

Comment: First, get rid of the `<center>` tag. I know it doesn't solve your problem, but it's icky.

Comment: Noted and fixed, thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add the answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the twitter widget will not work on local files. You can't request security information with local files. It works once the code is uploaded to a running website.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've copied the code correctly.

Specifically, you're missing the http:// at the start of your src.

```
<script charset="utf-8" 
    src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it's still having the same problem.